# Sitecore 8.2 update 3 mongodb conversion into sql server reporting db

Tags: mongodb, sql-database

We are using the Sitecore 8.2 update 3 version with `MongoDB`.

The data is being captured in the `MongoDB` but `Fact_Conversions` table  has no data.

1. What actually is to be done to have data in this table.
2. Also, I see that the data in reporting DB is populated with a latency of 24 
   hours.

Is there any way we can see it populated immediately?